# how to check output of 7 segment display written in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm currently new to verilog and wanted to type see if my code was correct. I've attached the code and the testbench but the values don't change. what do I do?
I am using quartus tool.
I copied the code from:
https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/binary-to-7-segment.html

my code:

```
module wow(
input       i_Clk,reset,
input [3:0] i_Binary_Num,
output  reg    o_Segment_A,
output  reg    o_Segment_B,
output  reg    o_Segment_C,
output  reg    o_Segment_D,
output  reg    o_Segment_E,
output  reg    o_Segment_F,
output  reg    o_Segment_G
);
reg [6:0]    r_Hex_Encoding = 7'h00;

// Purpose: Creates a case statement for all possible input binary numbers.
// Drives r_Hex_Encoding appropriately for each input combination.
always @(posedge i_Clk)

begin
  case (i_Binary_Num)
    4'b0000 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h7E;
    4'b0001 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h30;
    4'b0010 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h6D;
    4'b0011 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h79;
    4'b0100 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h33;          
    4'b0101 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h5B;
    4'b0110 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h5F;
    4'b0111 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h70;
    4'b1000 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h7F;
    4'b1001 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h7B;
    4'b1010 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h77;
    4'b1011 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h1F;
    4'b1100 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h4E;
    4'b1101 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h3D;
    4'b1110 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h4F;
    4'b1111 : r_Hex_Encoding <= 7'h47;
  endcase
end
 always @ (posedge i_Clk)
 begin

// r_Hex_Encoding[7] is unused
o_Segment_A <= r_Hex_Encoding[6];
o_Segment_B <= r_Hex_Encoding[5];
o_Segment_C <= r_Hex_Encoding[4];
o_Segment_D <= r_Hex_Encoding[3];
o_Segment_E <= r_Hex_Encoding[2];
o_Segment_F <= r_Hex_Encoding[1];
o_Segment_G <= r_Hex_Encoding[0];
end
endmodule
```

and the testbench:

```
module wow_testbench();
reg i_Clk, reset;
reg [3:0] i_Binary_Num;
wire o_Segment_A,o_Segment_B,o_Segment_C,o_Segment_D,o_Segment_E,o_Segment_F,o_Segment_G;

wow dut(i_Clk,reset,i_Binary_Num,o_Segment_A,o_Segment_B,o_Segment_C,o_Segment_D,o_Segment_E,o_Segment_F,o_Segment_G);
initial begin 
  begin
if(reset)
 i_Binary_Num <= 4'd0;
else
 i_Binary_Num <= i_Binary_Num + 4'd1;
end 
i_Clk=0;
forever #5 i_Clk=~i_Clk;
i_Binary_Num=4'd0;
end
endmodule
```

thank you in anticipation

Comment: It seems that testbench is incorrect. You didn't change `i_Binary_Num` while ticking the clock.

Comment: is it possible for @vlad to do the necessary corrections and post it? i tried my best but i seem to be lacking in the understanding of the concept on how to do it.sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems with your code. The main problem seems to be that you have a counter set up for i_Binary_Num, but it's only going to execute once in the initial loop and that's happening in zero time. Also, you have a reset value for i_Binary_Num, but the reset is never assigned a value, so if you look at the waveforms, you'll see i_Binary_Num equal to 7'hXX from time zero and never changing.

For testbenches, you do want events to happen on clock edges, but you can use non-synthesizable behavioural code. So you don't need to code your binary counter like a real counter implemented in the FPGA.

I've also noted that you don't have your begin-end pairs in your testbench matched correctly. This means that your forever loops is actually executing inside the initial statement, but after all the other initial statements have occurred.  Also, you really need to be consistent in your indentation and style. There is no magic value for indentation, but you should be consistent--pick 2, 3 or 4 spaces and use it that way all the time, or at least until you are in a corporate environment where there may be company wide coding standards.

I don't have time to actually set up a simulation project for you, but perhaps this will help:

```
module wow_testbench();
    reg       i_Clk = 1'b0;
    reg       reset;
    reg [3:0] i_Binary_Num;
    wire      o_Segment_A, o_Segment_B, o_Segment_C, o_Segment_D, o_Segment_E, o_Segment_F, o_Segment_G;

    wow dut(i_Clk, reset, i_Binary_Num, o_Segment_A, o_Segment_B, o_Segment_C, o_Segment_D, o_Segment_E, o_Segment_F, o_Segment_G);

    initial begin
        // perform a reset
        reset = 1'b0;
        @ (posedge i_Clk);
        reset = 1'b1;
        @ (posedge i_Clk);
        @ (posedge i_Clk);
        reset = 1'b0;

        // loop through numbers from 0 to 9, on positive clock edges
        for (i_Binary_Num = 4'd0; i_Binary_Num < 4'd10; i_Binary_Num = i_Binary_Num + 4'd1) 
            @ (posedge i_Clk);
        $stop;

    end // initial 

    // Create a clock with 10 ns period. 
    // Note that the clock was initialized to 0 when it was declared. 
    forever begin 
        #5 i_Clk = ~i_Clk;
    end // forever loop

endmodule
```

Notice that the testbench doesn't need to look like RTL code, it's behavioural. The signal assertions for stimulating the DUT are driven by clock edges, not just occurring after random delays (or no delay at all). Plus the use of consistent indentation makes it easy to follow the code and check that begin-end pairs are properly matched up. Finally, note that there is a $stop call to stop the simulation once all the stimulus has been sent.